# Trying to keep delegate alive

Tags: c#

First off, I'm completely, 100% new to any sort of programming, so my apologies if this is a really obvious error, but I can't find anything for it.

I am trying to implement a global hotkey in my program, and I need to keep this delegate alive to prevent the CallbackOnCollectedDelegate error, but the code I have gives me the two following build errors:

> Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

```
    public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);
    GC.KeepAlive(keyboardHookProc);

    public struct keyboardHookStruct {
        public int vkCode;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }

    const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
    const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
    const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Delegate is a type, you cannot declare it inside method body.

Comment: Token errors are due to the composition of your code

Comment: Can you post your complete code..Where are you declaring it ?

Comment: Does that help? That's the region it's contained in

Comment: Are you declaring it in a class or a method?

Comment: I'm declaring it in a class.

Comment: GC.KeepAlive(keyboardHookProc); cannot be there, must be in a method body.
It is a statement, it is meaningless outside of method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't keep a delegate *declaration* alive. Also don't use `GC.KeepAlive()` for this purpose; although it's meant for the "managed reference to unmanaged code" scenario, it's only usefull if the hook is set and cleared within the same method (see [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/634451/Csharp-and-GC-KeepAlive) for more information).

The problem with these hooks is that unmanaged code has the address of your delegate, but that reference is below the garbage collector's radar. So after a while the garbage collector starts cleaning up, and unmanaged code calls a now invalid address.

If your application keeps the keyboard hook up throughout its lifetime, a simple solution is assigning it to a static member:

```
static keyboardHookProc myKeyboardDelegate;

void SetHook()
{
    myKeyboardDelegate = new keyboardHookProc(MyHandler);
    UnmanagedMethod(myKeyboardDelegate);
}

int MyHandler(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
{
    ...
}
```

There are nicer ways though, you could wrap this in a class and hide the delegate from the rest of your application. Just make sure you keep a reference to the delegate you supply to unmanaged code until the hook is removed.